# Массив символов c латинским алфавитом

Tags: c

Мне нужно объявить массив символов, в котором бы хранился латинский алфавит. Покажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать.

Comment: А зачем вообще хранить где-то латинский алфавит? В любом случае, это будет просто набор кодов символов от 'A' до 'Z', каждый код можно получить в любой момент времени без необходимости для этого создавать массив.

Comment: Кодировки разные бывают...

Comment: В известных мне кодировках (да и вряд ли есть кодировка, где это не так, кроме символьных, где латиницы вообще нет) буквы латинского алфавита идут подряд, в алфавитном порядке. Если бы стояла задача перехода между кодировками, то тут одним латинским алфавитом не отделаешься.

Разве что стоит задача символы латиницы как-то перемешать, тогда создавать массив с алфавитом еще имеет смысл.

Comment: @insolor http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC

В СССР на её основе была создана кодировка ДКОИ-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
char lang[26];

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
    lang[i] = i + 65; // в массиве будут храниться все буквы в верхнем регистре.
```

Comment: Почему бы вместо "магического" числа (кода символа 'A') не записать сам символ 'A'?

Answer (score 9):

Самое простое (если помните латинский алфавит)

```
 char lang[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

Comment: МНе этот ответ кажется наиболее переносимым, т.к. в остальных ответах есть завязка на номера символов... Как известно, в таблице ASCII все латинские символы идут подряд.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>

void main()
{
    char mas[27];
    for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++) {
        mas[i] = (char) (i + 97);
        cout << mas[i] << endl;
    }
    getch();
}
```